# Set bool for UIButton Class in View controller (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a Custom Class for my UIButton. In this class I have the code below to draw the button. I would like the user to tap a button and toggle one part hidden/ not hidden. I don't know how to set the Bool value for this. Thanks

```
import UIKit

class CheckboxChecked: UIButton {

// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.

func drawTicked(#showTick: Bool) {

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(3, 3, 34, 34), cornerRadius: 10)
    UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 3
    rectanglePath.stroke()


    if (showTick) {
        //// Bezier Drawing
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 19.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(18.5, 26.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(30.5, 10.5))
        bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

        bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

        UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 3
        bezierPath.stroke()
    }
}


override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}


}
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You cannot draw outside `drawRect`. And in any case the drawing of a UIButton is not up to you (the docs explicitly forbid this).

Comment: You CAN draw outside the rectangle depending on your clipping properties I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this by using the code below.

I have a `UIButton` class with this:

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code

    //// Rectangle Drawing
    let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(3, 3, 34, 34), cornerRadius: 10)
    UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
    rectanglePath.lineWidth = 3
    rectanglePath.stroke()


    if (darwCheck == true) {
        //// Bezier Drawing
        var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(9.5, 19.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(18.5, 26.5))
        bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(30.5, 10.5))
        bezierPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;

        bezierPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;

        UIColor.darkGrayColor().setStroke()
        bezierPath.lineWidth = 3
        bezierPath.stroke()
    }
}
```

And in the `ViewController` I had a button that changed a global Boolean variable and redrew the button.

```
drawCheck = true
checkboxButton.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that instead you make a new `UIView` with an internal `UIButton` component - as well as what ever other component you want to hide.

You can then add a click handler to your `UIButton` portion of the control which would then control the `.visible` state of the other component.  In fact you could probably mock this up in a Playground.

And if you wanted to get really fancy you could look at `@IBInspectible`  Check out this post on custom components: https://www.weheartswift.com/make-awesome-ui-components-ios-8-using-swift-xcode-6/